# How to Switch to new tab automatically on button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I have taken 3 **TabPanel** inside **TabContainer** 
First with name Insert
2nd with name view
3rd is update

Now i want on click on the insert button the curson automatically switch to the new record entered in the view tab
And in view tab on click on the edit it automatically switch to Update panel

Please Help me with coding

This Is my Code

On MasterPage there is TabContainer

```
<td>
                <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="InsertTabPanel" HeaderText="Insert Data">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <p>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </p>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="ViewTabPanel" HeaderText="View Data">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <ul>
                                <a>
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                </a>
                            </ul>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="UpdateTabPanel" HeaderText="Update Data">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <p>
                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </p>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </asp:TabContainer>
            </td>
```

Then on Various Child Pages of the Master data in ContentPlaceholder Like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="123px" ImageUrl="~/admin/images/insert.jpg" Width="158px" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:Label ID="lblinsertion" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Euphemia" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#009900" Text="Insert Register User Information"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server" Text="UserName" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtusername" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtusername" ErrorMessage="Please Enter UserName" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblpassword" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtpassword" ErrorMessage="please Enter Password" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblrolename" runat="server" Text="RoleName" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtrolename" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtrolename" ErrorMessage="Plese Enter Role Name" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblemailid" runat="server" Text="Email Id" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtemailid" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style10">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtemailid" ErrorMessage="please Enter Email ID" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:Label ID="lblsecurityques" runat="server" Text="Security Question" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style7">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropsecques" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="160px" ValidationGroup="vg1" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style11">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropsecques" ErrorMessage="Please Enter SecurityQuestion" ValidationGroup="vg1" InitialValue="Select Security Question"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblsecurityans" runat="server" Text="Security Answer" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtsecans" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style9">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtsecans" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Security Answer" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3"></td>
            <td class="auto-style8">
                <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" OnClick="Login_Click" Text="Login" Width="125px" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblerrormesglogin" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder2">
    <asp:Panel ID="ViewPanel" runat="server">

         <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style4">
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="100px" ImageUrl="~/admin/images/view.jpg" Width="133px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Euphemia" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#009900" Text="View All Information"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
     <asp:GridView ID="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="3" Height="238px" OnRowCommand="gvLoginInfo_RowCommand" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UserName" DataField="UserName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Password" DataField="Password" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Role Name" DataField="RoleName" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email Id" DataField="EmailID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Security Question" DataField="SecurityQuestion" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Security Answer" DataField="SecurityAnswer" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LastLogin" DataField="LastLogin" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Record">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete The Record?')" Text="Delete This Record" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit  Record">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="update"  CommandName="upd" Text="Edit this Record" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
     <br />
  </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder3">
      <asp:Panel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="106px" ImageUrl="~/admin/images/update.jpg" Width="133px" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Euphemia" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#009900" Text="Update Your Information"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdusername" runat="server" Text="UserName" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdusername" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdusername" ErrorMessage="Please Enter UserName" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style15">
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdpassword" runat="server" Text="Password" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style15">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdpassword" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style15">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdpassword" ErrorMessage="please Enter Password" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdpassword" ErrorMessage="Password should contain atleast 8 alphanumeri digits" ValidationExpression="^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&amp;+=]).*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdrolename" runat="server" Text="RoleName" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdrolename" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdrolename" ErrorMessage="Plese Enter Role Name" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdemailid" runat="server" Text="Email Id" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdemailid" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdemailid" ErrorMessage="please Enter Email ID" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style13">
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdsecurityques" runat="server" Text="Security Question" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style13">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="dropupdsecques" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="134px" ValidationGroup="vg1">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style13">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropupdsecques" ErrorMessage="Please Enter SecurityQuestion" ValidationGroup="vg1" InitialValue="Select Security Question"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style14">
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdsecurityans" runat="server" Text="Security Answer" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style14">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdsecans" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style14">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdsecans" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Security Answer" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateLogin" runat="server"  Text="Update" Width="125px" ValidationGroup="vg1" OnClick="btnUpdateLogin_Click" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btncancel_Click" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```